# Running total in SQL based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

So I have the following two columns which I would like to create a running total column by date in SQL - here is a small snippet

| creation date | is_registered |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-30 | 1 |
| 2021-03-30 | 1 |
| 2021-03-31 | 1 |
| 2021-03-31 | 1 |

The issue I seem to have is the date has the time stamp and the reg column is in bit format, so I tried the following query

```
with reg as(      
    select
        cast([created_at] as date) as 'date',
        sum(cast([is_registered] as int)) as 'sum_of_reg'
    FROM [dbo].[Registrations]
    group by [created_at]
)
select
    [date],
    sum_of_reg,
    sum(sum_of_reg) over (order by [date]) as 'running total'
FROM reg
group by [date], sum_of_entries
order by [date] asc
```

However this returns the following:

| date | sum of reg | running total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-30 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-30 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-31 | 2 | 3 |

I would like to return

| date | sum of reg | running total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-30 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-03-31 | 2 | 3 |

Rather than combining the date into one distinct value, it still shows the same date twice.

I think it still treating the date separately due to the timestamps, but not sure of a way around it

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow supports Code Blocks. Also don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. Some methods of using single quotes for Aliases are deprecated and only works when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'Quantity'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'Quantity'`. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: If you add your sample data as DDL+DML it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: You need to aggregate first on each date, then you can do your "running aggregate".

Comment: It seems your initial data is not raw sample data, but part processed data. We need some actual sample data, and your desired results.

Comment: if you do `group by cast([created_at] as date)` then it'll be grouped by the date. You can also do `group by year([created_at]), month([created_at])` to sum over each month in the year.

Comment: Thanks @iSR5 - that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have the wrong grouping clause in the `reg` CTE, you need `cast([created_at] as date)`**.

The outer `group by` is not necessary

> The default window in an `OVER` clause (when there is an `ORDER BY`) is unfortunately `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is rarely what people expect.
> **You must specify `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` explicitly.**

```sql
with reg as(      
    select
        cast([created_at] as date) as [date],
        sum(cast([is_registered] as int)) as [sum_of_reg]
    FROM [dbo].[Registrations]
    group by cast([created_at] as date)
)
select
    [date],
    sum_of_reg,
    sum(sum_of_reg) over (order by [date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as [running total]
FROM reg
order by [date] asc
```

You can even do this in a single level, by using a window function on top of normal aggregation.

```
select
    cast([created_at] as date) as [date],
    sum(cast([is_registered] as int)) as [sum_of_reg],
    sum(sum(cast([is_registered] as int)))
      over (order by [date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as [running total]
FROM [dbo].[Registrations]
group by cast([created_at] as date)
order by [date] asc
```